# Express.static is not serving login page

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I set the homepage to login.html, but why does the homepage be index.html?

I tried to delete index.html. It turns out that the web shows login.html so I was wondering.

**app.js**

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path');
const app = express()
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000

express.static('public')
app.use(express.static('public'))

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended : true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
     res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'/public/login.html'))
})

app.listen(PORT, () => {
   console.log(`Server is running on port : ${PORT}`)
})
```

**public folder**

```
public
   ---> css
   ---> img
   index.html
   login.html
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In regards to **serve-static**, the documentation says:

> By default this module will send “index.html” files in response to a request on a directory. To disable this set false or to supply a new index pass a string or an array in preferred order.
>   http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/serve-static.html

In your example, you can disable this default behavior by setting the **"index"** option to **"false"**:

```
app.use(express.static("public", { index: false }));
```

There is also an option to pass an array (as mentioned in the documentation):

```
app.use(express.static("public", { 'index': ['login.html', 'index.htm'] }));
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution but I get a new problem, that the images in the public folder can't be loaded.

Comment: @Merphy I can't replicate your issue. I created a codesandbox, take a look:
https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-http-vxd6f?file=/src/index.js
If you try to open the image as https://vxd6f.sse.codesandbox.io/7.jpg, it will load. Can you give me more information so we can try to figure this out?